# Python,file handling

Tags: python, csv, file-handling

```
import csv
from _csv import writer
f1=open("formatted.txt")
with open("write.csv","wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for line in f1:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

I have a text file of some uniform records. When I am trying to get that into an excel file, I am getting each character separate in each cell. 
How can we make sure that each specified value will go in separate columns?

[input text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMiw9.jpg)

[output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujptn.jpg)

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image

Comment: What's the point of your code at all? Your Input file already looks valid. All the code is doing is reading and immediately writing the same data. At best, nothing changes, at worst the interleaved read/write will corrupt the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from csv import writer

f1 = open('formatted.txt').read()

with open("write.csv", "w+") as csv_file:
    writer = writer(csv_file)
    for line in f1.split('\n'):
        writer.writerow(line.split())
```

Comment: it is working ,but after every write of line one new line is being added.